# Labeling references in a second document identical to the labeling of a first document

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I am submitting a paper to a journal, who request the following:

Please relabel the references in the Supplemental Material to render the numbering identical to that in the main bibliography (even though it might look weird if viewing the Supplement alone). If the first reference in the Supplement is cited as reference 42 of the main text, then its number in the Supplement should also be 42, not 1 or S1.

In other words, I have a ms.tex file and a supplement.tex file. The ms.tex contains all of the references that the supplement uses (and more!) in its bibliography. I now need to find a way to make the supplement use the number of the ms.tex.

I honestly do not know how to go about this. I was thinking of something with `\nocite` but I am not sure that would work.