# Manually adjusting a citation number

Tags: bibtex, citing

For publication in a specific journal, I need a second document to use the citation number of the first (they share the same .bib file). So in the second document I will have, lets say, 3 different \cite{} entries, resulting in a bibliography numbered [1], [2], [3]. I need to change those numbers to be something like [44], [12], [31], based on what the numbers are in the first document.

There is potentially a way of doing this nicely, [but I have not been able to figure it out](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/669465/labeling-references-in-a-second-document-identical-to-the-labeling-of-a-first-do). So I am now down to just adjust the numbers manually. But how can this done? Is there some auxillary file that contains the numbering, upon compilation, that I can edit? I have not been able to find it.

Comment: It would be better to bounty your original question, not repost it as a duplicate.

Comment: My intention is not to duplicate the question per se, but to ask for a way to manually adjust the numbering. I don't really consider that to be a solution to the problem posed in the other question, since I have ~80 citations to renumber, but I am a bit desperate (and the journal is not taking no for an answer).